# Python AI chatbot - get data from XLSX file not giving me accurate results

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, openai-api

I'm trying to allow an XLSX file upload that uses OpenAI API to ask questions based on the uploaded dataset. Thus far I have this working for PDF and Word, but Excel is proving difficult! I can upload a file and get responses based on data, but it's not giving me the answers I'd expect (ie. it's missing certain fields, duplicating and so forth).

I've tried a few different ways, using Pandas and openpyxl but the same issue, so I come asking for guidance.

Right now, here is my current code to get the data from XLSX:

```
    import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from docx import Document
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

class Agent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Hardcoded OpenAI API key
        self.openai_api_key = "sk-KEY"
        self.embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=self.openai_api_key)
        self.text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)

        self.llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=self.openai_api_key)

        self.chat_history = None
        self.chain = None
        self.db = None

    def ask(self, question: str) -> str:
        if self.chain is None:
            response = "Please, add a document."
        else:
            response = self.chain({"question": question, "chat_history": self.chat_history})
            response = response["answer"].strip()
            self.chat_history.append((question, response))
        return response

    def ingest(self, file_path: os.PathLike, file_name: str) -> None:
        file_ext = file_name.split(".", 1)[1].lower()

        if file_ext == 'pdf':
            print(file_path)
            loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path)
            documents = loader.load()
            splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.split_documents(documents)


        elif file_ext == 'docx':
            doc = Document(file_path)
            text = "\n".join([paragraph.text for paragraph in doc.paragraphs])
            splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents([text])


        elif file_ext == 'xlsx':
            # wb = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
            # ws = wb.active
            # text = []
            # for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            #     text.extend(row)
            # splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents([str(cell) for cell in text])

            # __________________________________________________
            # uploading but not understanding Q

            # workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
            # splitted_documents = []  # Initialize an empty list to store document fragments
            # for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
            #     sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
            #     print(f"Title = {sheet.title}")
            #     for row in sheet.rows:
            #         for cell in row:
            #             if isinstance(cell, openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell):
            #                 # Skip this cell
            #                 continue
            #             print(f"{cell.column_letter}{cell.row} = {cell.value}")
            #             splitted_documents.append(str(cell.value))  # Append cell value to the list
            # # After processing all cells, create documents from the accumulated cell values
            # splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents(splitted_documents)


            # __________________________________________________
            # Splitting document by row but inaccurate
            # workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
            # splitted_documents = []  # Initialize an empty list to store document fragments
            # for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
            #     sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
            #     print(f"Title = {sheet.title}")
            #     for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            #         row_text = " ".join(str(cell) for cell in row if cell is not None)
            #         splitted_documents.append(row_text)
            # # After processing all rows, create documents from the accumulated row values
            # splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents(splitted_documents)



            # __________________________________________________
            # one document but doesn't seem to read it
            # workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
            # document_text = ""  # Initialize an empty string to store the entire document content
            # for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
            #     sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
            #     print(f"Title = {sheet.title}")
            #     for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            #         row_text = " ".join(str(cell) for cell in row if cell is not None)
            #         document_text += row_text + "\n"  # Concatenate row text with newline separator
            # # After processing all rows, create a single document from the entire content
            #         print(document_text)
            # splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents([document_text])



            # workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_path)
            # splitted_documents = []  # Initialize an empty list to store document fragments
            # for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
            #     sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
            #     sheet_data = []
            #     for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            #         row_data = []
            #         for cell in row:
            #             if cell is not None:
            #                 row_data.append(str(cell))
            #             else:
            #                 row_data.append("")  # Treat None as empty string
            #         sheet_data.append(row_data)
            #     splitted_documents.append("\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in sheet_data))
            #     splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents(splitted_documents)

            df_excel = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None)  # Read all sheets into a dictionary
            lines = []
            for sheet_name, sheet_data in df_excel.items():
                sheet_text = ""
                for index, row in sheet_data.iterrows():
                    row_text = " ".join(str(cell) for cell in row if not pd.isna(cell))
                    sheet_text += row_text + "\n"
                lines.append(sheet_text)
            splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.create_documents(lines)


        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported file format")
    
        if self.db is None:
            self.db = FAISS.from_documents(splitted_documents, self.embeddings)
            self.chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(self.llm, self.db.as_retriever())
            self.chat_history = []
        else:
            self.db.add_documents(splitted_documents)

    def forget(self) -> None:
        self.db = None
        self.chain = None
        self.chat_history = None
```

I've tried saving the full XLSX file, saving by row and even by cell; but it just can't seem to understand the data around it (ie. if I ask 'how many products are in this data' it doesn't give me the correct amount, and it has no idea of 'what was the overall profit'.

I'm using an example finance.xlsx dataset, which you can view [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962) via microsoft

Comment: Why do you need to process embeddings ? Don't you want to make ChatGPT search for the answers using a standard well engineered textual prompt ?

Comment: The scenario here is I want to use ChatGPT purely as a LLM, but only use the data I upload as the dataset to get information from

Comment: You're better off fine-tuning ChatGPT on your data - See: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning. I'd also recommend looking into `llama` or others so that you can avoid the overhead that ChatGPT slaps in your face.

Comment: Most recently I used langchain with a csv file and the results were good. I think you can achieve your goal by converting the xlsx file to csv using pandas and then using langchain. I hope this works well for you. I can share some code with you if you want.